# Pyinstaller does not support Com Server and py2exe does not maintained in recent python3

Tags: python, pyinstaller, py2exe, python-2to3

We are migrating a project from python 2 to 3 that uses com server. Previously we use py2exe which works pretty well in python 2, but it is no longer maintained in the recent Python 3 release. We also tried Pyinstaller, unfortunately, it is not supporting com server from like 5 years ago. The last resort for us could be use python 3.4 which is the latest version py2exe support. But before that, just asking the question here if anyone has a similar situation and has a proper solution.

Comment: "com server"? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Legorooj I meant Microsoft win32 com server exe http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndWin32com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deploy a win32 COM server with PyInstaller, due to the fact that the bootloader doesn't provide that.

If you'd like to have COM support, you'll need to program it yourself; in other words, create a python script which runs a COM server, serving your DLL/exe. You could base this off the py2exe code.